# What is the minimum scrape_interval in Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I am wondering what the minimum time is for Prometheus' `scrape_interval` parameter. According to the [Prometheus Documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/), the value for this parameter needs to follow a regex which seems to me that only intervals equal or greater than 1 second are allowed, since, e.g. "1ms" or "0.01s" do not match this regex. In my application however, I would like to have scraping in milliseconds, so I am interested in whether this is possible with Prometheus.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: which is the problem you want to solve with that? i have the feeling if you need a data point every millisecond, prometheus might not be the right tool for that.

Answer (score 5):

While Prometheus supports scrape intervals smaller than one second as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66628731/274937), it isn't recommended to use `scrape_interval` values smaller than one second because of the following issues:

- Non-zero network delays between Prometheus and scrape target. These delays are usually in the range `0.1ms - 100ms` depending on the distance between Prometheus and scrape target.
- Non-zero delays in scrape target's response handler, which generates the response for Prometheus.

These non-deterministic delays may introduce big relative errors to scrape timings for `scrape_interval` values smaller than one second.

Too small `scrape_interval` values also may result in scrape errors if the target cannot be scraped during the configured scrape interval. In this case Prometheus would store `up=0` metric for every unsuccessful scrape. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/#automatically-generated-labels-and-time-series) about `up` metric.

P.S. If you need storing high-frequency samples into time series, then it would be better pushing these samples directly to a monitoring system, which supports push protocols for data ingestion. For example, VictoriaMetrics supports popular push protocols such as Influx, Graphite, OpenTSDB, CSV, DataDog etc. - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-time-series-data) for details. It supports timestamps with millisecond precision. If you need even higher precision for timestamps, then take a look at InfluxDB - it supports timestamps with nanosecond precision. Note that too high precision for timestamps usually leads to increased resource usage - disk space, RAM, CPU.

Disclosure: I work on VictoriaMetrics.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/), the minimum value you can give for the `scrape_interval` seems to be `0` (according to the given regex in the docs).

Regex - `((([0-9]+)y)?(([0-9]+)w)?(([0-9]+)d)?(([0-9]+)h)?(([0-9]+)m)?(([0-9]+)s)?(([0-9]+)ms)?|0)`

According to this regex, you can specify `scrape_interval` in `ms` as well. But you need to specify it as `0s1ms`. This is because if you specify the time as `1ms`; `1m` will match with minutes and remaining `s` will cause an error (didn't really test this scenario, but looks like this is the expected outcome by looking at the regex).

Comment: Thanks, @shan1024 ! This is the answer I was looking for. I got confused with the regex in the documentation. So ms works. But obviously, setting scrape_intervals to <1s is not what Prometheus is designed for ;)