# How can I get correct metric for pod status?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, promql, kube-state-metrics

I'm trying to get the pod status in Grafana through Prometheus in a GKE cluster.

`kube-state-metrics` has been installed together with Prometheus by using the [prometheus-community/prometheus](https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts) and [grafana](https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts) Helm charts.

I tried to know the pod status through `kube_pod_status_phase{exported_namespace=~".+-my-namespace", pod=~"my-server-.+"}`, but I get only "Running" as a result.
In other words, in the obtained graph I can see only a straight line at the value 1 for the running server. I can't get when the given pod was pending or in another state different from Running.

I am interested in the starting phase, after the pod is created, but before it is running.

Am I using the query correctly? Is there another query or it could be due to something in the installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Pending status for the Pod, I think you should use instead `kube_pod_status_phase{exported_namespace=~".+-my-namespace", pod=~"my-server-.+", phase="Pending"}` . Not sure what it does when you don't put the phase in your request but I suspect it just  renders the number of Pods whatever the state is. In your case is always 1.

Comment: Thank you! I already tried what you said and unfortunately I got 0 in that case...

Comment: May be because your app is just in Pending state for a few milliseconds and as the prometheus scraping interval is in order of seconds ...  What do you want to do with this metric ?  If you just want to see an app pod status in realtime , i would recommend using other tools ( not metric based). If it''s to test your monitoring then may be you shoud find a way to make your pod pending for a longer periiod

Comment: Yeah I supposed that this could the reason. Probably the startup is too fast. I would like to know how much resources (cpu/memory) are needed during the pod startup (before being ready) and I want to use `kube_pod_status` to "select" only that period of time.

Comment: Oki. So I think making your app pod pending is not the best way. You can possibly try to set scraping_interval to 0 ( seems possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549609/what-is-the-minimum-scrape-interval-in-prometheus ) . But this means heavy network/disk usage so just for experiment I would say.

Comment: For each status label there's a boolean value, so they will be displayed concomitantly no matter what, be it 0 or 1.
@behanzin777 no, it won't be always 1, it will only display information related to the `Pending` status, i.e. if the pod has that status or not!

Comment: So after the pod has changed its status to `Running`, the `Pending` metric will show 0, while the `Running` metric will show 1. But both return values concomitantly.